# How bicycles automatically steer into the fall - have we been using the wrong physics in trying to explain it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

There are many posts/questions discussing the physics of a bicycle front wheel. The ones trying to understand the self-turning motion all try to find where the torque comes from that turns the wheel. What if we are looking for the wrong thing and a torque isn't needed?

There is still no scientific consensus on how the front wheel of a bicycle automatically turns into the direction of the lean/fall. Some say it is a result of one or a combination of the following: caster effect, gyroscopic precession, camber thrust, etc. There is even an argument for the weight of the forward extending handlebars creating the wheel turning torque when the bike leans. What we are looking for is the mechanical source that creates the torque which turns the front wheel. But what if a wheel can change rolling direction without a direction changing torque and it is simply the geometry of the wheel in motion that creates this change in rolling direction?

A rolling coin that is leaning/falling constantly changes rolling direction without a wheel turning torque. This is exactly what a bike’s front wheel does when the bike rolls and leans/falls. If you look at the instantaneous horizontal velocity components of the curved path rolling coin, you will see that these velocities are always parallel. If they weren't parallel then that would be evidence of a vertical axis torque.

Looking at a straight rolling wheel: The side view shows that the instantaneous velocities of every part of the wheel are perpendicular to an axis through the contact point. If we look from the top, we see that the horizontal components of all non-zero velocities are parallel at any instant in time.
[image]

When a single wheel rolls and falls: The rolling falling wheel (we’ll call it a tumbling wheel) is just a wheel rolling at an angle to its wheel plane. The top view reveals the same as above - the horizontal components of all non-zero velocities are parallel at any instant in time.

[image]

The tumbling wheel rolls 90 degrees: Looking from the top, the wheel plane goes through a clockwise change in orientation on a horizontal plane (the road) by 30 degrees from stage 1 to stage 7. There is also a clockwise rotation on a vertical plane of 90 degrees. Attach a bicycle to it and it looks like the bicycle front wheel turned 30 degrees as the bicycle rolls forward and falls/leans. Looking at the geometry in motion; the front wheel does not turn and thus does not have any component of rotational velocities on a horizontal plane. Those velocities are all parallel at any instant in time. The front wheel changes rolling direction without any wheel-turning torque.

[image]

This tumbling motion can also be observed when a wheel/disc is rolled onto a rotating turntable. The wheel/disc keeps changing rolling direction and we perceive it to be turning but it is not in the way we think. It is constantly tumbling into a different rolling direction, which is toward the direction the wheel/disc leans, as a result of oncoming turntable surface that is not parallel to the wheel plane (rolling direction).

When a bike rolls and falls/leans, the front wheel tumbles and creates the torque that turns the attached fork through to the handlebars. The geometry of the bicycle, more specifically the head tube angle, must allow the unconstrained motion of the tumbling front wheel.

The images below show the bicycle front wheel following the same motion of the above tumbling wheel images and it looks to us like the bicycle wheel is turning but we know it is not.

[image]
[image]
To allow the front wheel to tumble, the bike’s head tube angle has to be within a certain range. Below shows which angles work and which angles do not work.

The figures below show a stationary bike with different head angles as the wheel is turned and is compared to the tumbling wheel below each figure.

Starting with head angles the don’t allow the front wheel to tumble:

Fig 1 -NO-  A 100 degree head tube angle creates a counterclockwise rotation on the vertical axis plane. This head angle does not allow the wheel to tumble.
[image]

Fig 2 -NO- A 90 degree head angle does not allow rotation on a vertical plane.
[image]

Fig 3 -NO- A 0 degree head angle does not allow the change in orientation on a horizontal plane.
[image]

Fig 4 -YES– A 45 degree head angle allows the dual plane clockwise rotation (change in orientation). The vertical plane rotation and degree of lean are very closely matched through each stage. This tells us that, to a varying degree of freedom, any angle between 0 and 90 will allow a wheel to tumble.
[image]

We see the front wheel turn when the bike rolls and falls. When the bicycle corners and the front wheel is fixed we do not see the front wheel turning. But when we examine the instantaneous horizontal component velocities (see below), we see that these velocities are in different directions and are perpendicular to a turn center axis. This is the definition of rotation/turning of a rolling wheel.
[image]
The ironic thing is that cornering vehicle wheels are actually turning. It’s just imperceptible. When you are cornering in your car and the orientations of the front wheels are fixed, all four wheels of the car are rotating on a vertical axis which is why they individually travel along curved paths. There is a torque at each wheel that constantly turns them which is created by a mechanism that is common to most self-guided vehicles such as airplanes, boats, snowmobiles, bicycles, etc.
The video link below describes this cornering mechanism.

https://youtu.be/-UIir0wNIEI

Comment: Bicycles typically have a curved front fork to increase the castor effect. I notice that your bicycles do not. Might this not be part of the problem?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think caster effect has an influence on why the wheel changes travels direction.

Comment: Hello @Qmechanic. The PSE website has many many posts/questions discussing the physics of a bicycle front wheel. The ones trying to understand the self-turning motion all try to find where the torque comes from. My question asks “what if there isn't a torque needed?”. Please read my description. Please allow this question exploring nature to be allowed.

Comment: Qmechanic merely edited your question; it was closed by the votes of three regular users in accordance with our review process. The amount and size of pictures in this question makes it rather hard to read, and really it is not clear what sort of answers you expect to the question "what if there isn't a torque needed?". physics.SE does best with *clear*, *specific* questions, while this seems to be more of a  somewhat vague discussion prompt for your ideas about rolling motion and torques.

Comment: Thanks @ACuriousMind. I took out a lot of info and focus only on the simple geometry and torque. The simple question is “What if a wheel turning torque is not needed?”

Comment: I think a lot of people are just confused as to how to help you; the essence of your question comes down to a misconception. The front wheel's angular momentum has changed, at least direction, and rate of change of angular momentum is the torque, necessarily by mathematical accounting of calculus. Other than that, it is difficult to even work out what it is you are asking.

Comment: When you manually turn the bike handlebars, a torque turns the front wheel’s rolling direction. If you take the wheel off of the bike and roll it at an angle to its plane (tumbling wheel), the rolling direction changes without a torque. These are two examples of changing the rolling direction; one with a torque the other without a torque. To this day, all discussions have been about trying to find how a torque is created that changes the rolling direction. Could the bike wheel be changing direction without a torque. I think so. Does anybody else?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent When the front wheel is being manually turned, there will be horizontal velocity components in different directions (i.e. rotation of the wheel with respect to the horizontal plane - the road) at any instant. This is evidence of a vertical axis torque. The tumbling wheel on the other hand has only parallel horizontal velocity components, at any instant, thus is not rotating with respect to the road. No vertical axis torque. Both are changing rolling direction at any instant.

Comment: See, this is precisely what everybody is worried about. I told you that it is absolutely necessary for there to be a torque in order for the turning to happen, yet you still continue to think that "rolling direction changes without a torque". You are asking us "why cannot it be 1+1=14?"

Comment: @ACuriousMind My question is getting upvotes but no one can provide input because…… I don't know why. This question appears to be understood by some but not all.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent A free rolling wheel has horizontal velocity components of all parts except for the stationary contact point/patch. Those instantaneous component velocities are all going in one direction - are all parallel. This is also the case when the wheel rolls and falls. There is no vertical axis direction changing torque when rolling and falling though it keeps changing rolling direction. We perceive it to be turning but our knowledge of kinematics tells us it is not. It is changing rolling direction but not the way we think. You have to look a little closer to see this.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Something comparable to consider: A ball is rolling along a horizontal surface and comes to an unlevel part where it changes rolling direction. Or better yet, a ball rolling forward on a rotating turntable constantly changes rolling direction. Even better, make it the wheel on a turntable and it tumbles into different rolling directions. All examples change the rolling direction without a vertical axis direction turning torque.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Did you need assistance understanding how the geometry in motion changes a wheel's rolling direction differently than how a vertical axis torque changes a wheel’s rolling direction?

Comment: @Qmechanic. There appears to be a lack of understanding about how the geometry in motion changes a wheel rolling direction differently than how a vertical axis torque changes a wheel’s rolling direction. As a result my question sits in limbo. Please help.

Comment: @ACuriousMind   My question gets up-votes but still sits in limbo. I also notice that almost every time I make a comment a down-vote instantly appears. What more can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: "...\[looking for] where the torque comes from that turns the wheel. What if...torque isn't needed?" Then you would be speaking a different language from all of the physicists in the room. If anything at all causes something that was not turning to start turning, then a physicist will call it "torque." Not speaking their language will make it harder for you to get them interested in answering your questions.

Comment: Thanks, @Solomon Slow. Consider a rolling ball on a flat level surface experiencing a side wind, or better yet, a ball rolling on a tilted flat surface. They travel along a curved path, changing rolling direction continuously without a turning torque - a vertical axis/normal to the rolling surface torque. One way a physicist would prove that this torque does not exist is to look at the instantaneous horizontal non-zero velocity components at any moment of travel. The directions of those velocities are always parallel. I am trying to show how a bicycle front wheel can do the exact same thing.

Comment: It’s easy to understand how a continuous vertical axis torque changes a rolling wheel’s travel direction. This happens when you turn the car steering wheel or bike handlebars as the vehicle rolls and the wheel(s) travel along a curved path. Simple stuff. But when your car/bike is cornering, and you are not turning the steering wheel/handlebars, the wheel(s) still travel along a curved path(s). This is where it gets really interesting, even to a physicist. What phenomenon/mechanism continuously changes the cornering wheel's rolling direction? This is also addressed in this post.

Comment: The instantaneous velocities of different particles belonging to the same rolling ball do not all point in the same direction. Consider a particle on the leading edge of the ball. The vertical component of its velocity is downward. But, the vertical component of a particle on the trailing edge is upward. Clearly not parallel to each other.

Comment: Consider your ball, rolling at a constant speed on a flat, level plane, when it encounters a place where the surface tilts to the right. If the ball's rotational axis changes as it curves to the right, that's because the _torque_ that changed its rotational axis was provided by the interaction of static friction with the surface upon which it was rolling and the ball's inertia. (If there is no friction, then the ball's rotational motion will not change even despite the fact that its translational motion changes.)

Comment: Thanks, @Solomon Slow. To your first comment: “HORIZONTAL velocity components”. These are the component velocities with respect to the rolling surface. Yes, they are always parallel at any instant in time and yet, through time, they are constantly changing direction resulting in a curved travel path. No turning torque occurs while the ball keeps changing direction.

Comment: To your second comment: Sounds good. Of course, this is all about how a ball/wheel changes travel direction with respect to the rolling surface. A rolling ball cannot fall but a rolling wheel can fall. And when the rolling wheel falls, its plane changes orientation with respect to the rolling surface. And its plane defines the rolling direction. The rolling direction changes without a turning torque. It’s all described above.

Comment: @ACuriousMind     * ? *